# How can I convert a 2d array to an array of objects with all unique property names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I need to take a a 2d array and generate an array of objects. Simple enough, but I need to also generate a unique ID for each object. E.g.

INPUT:

```
[
   ['This is text 1', 'word 1', 'This is text 1'], 
   ['This is text 2', 'word 2', 'This is text 1']
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{
   1: 'This is text 1'.
   2: 'word 1',
   3: 'This is text 1'
},
{
   4: 'This is text 2'.
   5: 'word 2',
   6: 'This is text 2'
}]
```

This is for a React project and each original array item represents a paragraph so in my example I have two paragraphs. I am generating components out of certain words in a string which is why its split. React requires unique keys.

I have this working with a nested map & reduce solution:

```
let counter = 0;
arr.map(item =>
    item.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const result = acc;
        result[counter] = curr;
        counter += 1;
        return result;
    }, {})
);
```

I am not a huge fan of this solution due to the nested loop. I want to reduce the complexity of this by removing the nested loop.

What are some of my options?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want. Could you post actual input data and an example of the expected outcome?

Comment: Converting an 2d array is an inherently nested task though. I think you did alright. Could only *try* to conceal the loop by using more confusing build-ins like `arr.map(paragraph => Object.fromEntries(Array.from(paragraph, word => [counter++, word])))`.